# git add doesn't add files?

Tags: git, github

I have really been confused by this one. After pulling from a repo, I modified the files and attempted to add and commit them. However after adding the two files with `git add [file]` as well as `git add .`, `git add -A`, and `git add -u`, I always get this output:

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   ../.DS_Store
#   .DS_Store
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Why doesn't git add my files?

Comment: You'd be better off adding `.DS_Store` to a `.gitignore` file, since Git really shouldn't be tracking those (they're just OS-specific cache files).

Comment: Not really a top priority right now, but Ill keep that in mind :P

Comment: Are you adding new files or modifying existing files?

Comment: @Jumhyn It's probably worthwhile to do it in this case as well, since those files get updated by the OS.

Comment: @manojlds Modifying existing files. It may be important to note that this problem didn't arise until after I pulled from the repo after another member of the team made a change

Comment: Are you using a case insensitive file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are editing existing files ( as in already tracked files ), after editing ( and saving ) them, do a `git status` - you must see a line saying they have been modified (`Changes not staged for commit`).

If that doesn't happen, you are not actually editing / saving the files. Make sure you are saving them.

Comment: This was it. Somehow the program I was using lost track of the files on disk and was just saving into the ether.